# Append Child will not work on concatenated array items

Tags: javascript

I have queried the `DOM` getting all the `DOM` elements with a particular tag (item), and stored them in an array. I then cloned that array and concatenated 2 copies of the clone to the array essentially tripling the amount of elements from 20 to 60. So after I am done I have a new array with 60 elements. When I try to loop through those 60 elements and surround every 6 of them with a parent div, `appendChild` method will not append the copies which were concatenated to the array. It will only work on the original 20 which I assume are from the original clone.

```
function buildProductsList_() {
  var concatNumber = 1;
  cloneItemArray = baseItemElementsByAttribute.slice();

  if (baseItemElementsCount % baseItemElementsPerSlide == 0) {
    return false;
  }

  while (baseItemElementsCount * concatNumber %
      baseItemElementsPerSlide != 0) {
    concatNumber++;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < concatNumber; i++) {
    newItemList = newItemList.concat(cloneItemArray);
  }

  newItemListCount = newItemList.length;
  offsetFrameCount = newItemListCount % baseItemElementsPerSlide;
}

function constructCarouselSlides_() {

  for (i = 0; i < newItemListCount; i += baseItemElementsPerSlide) {
    var offset = baseItemElementsPerSlide;

    if (offsetFrameCount + i == newItemListCount) {
      offset = offsetFrameCount;
    }

    var section = newItemList.slice(i, i + offset);
    var itemsClones = itemsInstance.cloneNode();

    for (j = 0; j < section.length; j++) {
      itemsClones.appendChild(section[j]);
    }

    carouselContainer.appendChild(itemsClones);
  }
}
```

See Screenshot: The first 6 items elements do not have any of the item elements appended to them. It seems to only have worked on the original 20 item elements. Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshot of DOM
https://www.dropbox.com/s/55n0y8j7ezet1u7/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-23%20at%203.00.50%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a copy of an array of DOM elements with `.slice()` does NOT make new DOM elements.  It just makes a second array that contains references to the same set of DOM elements.  So, when you try to append those same DOM element references from the cloned array, it just moves them from where they were originally.

If you want a new array of newly created DOM elements, you will have to clone each element in the array to actually create a new set of DOM elements.  Here's a function that will clone an array of DOM nodes:

```
function cloneDOMArray(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
        return item.cloneNode();
    });
}
```

It returns an array of cloned nodes.

---

**More Explanation:**

At the core of this is in Javascript, a primitive such as a number or boolean is assigned by copying the value.

```
var a = 2;
var b = a;
a = 3;
console.log(a);   // 3 (shows the newly assigned value)
console.log(b);   // 2 (it has a copy of the original value of a)
```

But, objects in Javascript (which includes DOM objects) are assigned by pointer:

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
x.innerHTML = "Hello";
var y = x;
x.innerHTML = "Goodbye";
console.log(y.innerHTML);   // "Goodbye"
console.log(x.innerHTML);   // "Goodbye"
```

So, when you assign one object to two different variables, each variable points at the exact same object.  If you modify that object, you will see that modification through both variables (because they both point at the exact same object).

So, if you have an array of DOM elements references and you then make a copy of that array with `.slice()`, you will just have two arrays with the exact same set of DOM element references in it.

```
var x = document.getElementById("one");
var y = document.getElementById("two");
var items = [x,y];
var copyItems = items.slice(0);
console.log(items[0] === copyItems[0]);    // true, same element reference
```

So, when you assign an object to a second variable and you want the second variable to contain a copy of that object, you have to explicitly make a copy.  How you best make a copy depends upon the object (you would do it differently for an array of DOM element references vs. an array of something else).

Comment: Read theory about `value` and `reference`. The array contains references to the DOM elements, that's why you are just copying those references and not the elements itself.

Comment: Thank you, looking into the value and reference now and should get a chance to implement your function tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome, thank God, it worked like a charm. I appreciate you sharing your knowledge with me. I struggled at work for a day on this.